# Inpainting: which algorithm should I choose?

Tags: image-processing, python

I have a 3D data set sampled on a regular grid shown in the Figure below. This data can be interpreted as an image where the point altitude is equivalent to the pixel intensity value.

In the middle of my 3D data, I have a peak, that becomes a bright spot when the data is interpreted as an image.
My goal is to remove this hot spot from my data.

I was told to try some image inpainting techniques to remove it without introducing too many artifacts. After searching available implementations, I've found two algorithms already implemented in the [opencv](http://docs.opencv.org/master/modules/photo/doc/inpainting.html) library:

- one is the *Navier-Stokes Inpainting* by Bertalmio *et al.*;
- the other one is a *fast marching based* approach by Telea;

but I don't know which one to use.

Is any of these methods suitable for my task? Which of these methods (if any) should I use?

Thank you.

[image: my image]

Comment: I've rephrased the question to make clear that you are asking about algorithm suitability and not about implementation. I will answer on SO later if the question does not get re-opened here.

Comment: Thanks for your revision. It could be used to pure 3d data set? How to estimate the result precisely?visual check?